# How to Convert an Outer Join Select Query to MERGE in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, sql-update, oracle12c

How can I convert this simple Outer Join to MERGE to update `FT.SS` to a certain value for the selected rows:

```
SELECT FT.SS FROM FT_T FT LEFT OUTER JOIN DC_T DC
    ON FT.ID = DC.ID AND FT.CN = DC.CN
WHERE FT.GID = 'AB' AND SS = 'C' AND FT.DEL = 'N' AND PR_S IS NULL AND EN_S IS NULL
AND (DC.ID IS NULL OR DC.SIGNED IS NULL);
```

It's relatively easy to do it with `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE FT_T FTX
SET FTX.SS = 'X'
WHERE FT.GID = 'AB' AND SS = 'C' AND FT.DEL = 'N' 
    AND PR_S IS NULL AND EN_S IS NULL 
    AND (FTX.ID, FTX.CN) = (
       SELECT FT.ID, FT.CN FROM FT_T FT LEFT OUTER JOIN DC_T DC
           ON FT.ID = DC.ID AND FT.CN = DC.CN
       WHERE FT.GID = 'AB' AND SS = 'C' AND FT.DEL = 'N' AND PR_S IS NULL AND EN_S IS NULL 
         AND (DC.ID IS NULL OR DC.SIGNED IS NULL)
)
```

But can it be done with `MERGE`?

Comment: That update statement will never work in it's present state. You can't reference the columns of table aliased inside the subquery (FT) outside. Also, If there are multiple rows returned, it will give an error if you are using `=`' . Perhaps you meant `WHERE FTX.GID ...... AND.(FTX.ID, FTX.CN) IN`?

Comment: @KaushikNayak You are right. I corrected it in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your merge statement would look like:

```
MERGE INTO ft_t tgt
USING (SELECT ft.id,
              ft.cn
       FROM   ft_t ft
              LEFT OUTER JOIN dc_t dc ON ft.id = dc.id AND ft.cn = dc.cn
       WHERE  ft.gid = 'AB'
       AND    ft.ss = 'C'
       AND    ft.del = 'N'
       AND    ft.pr_s IS NULL
       AND    ft.en_s IS NULL
       AND    (dc.id IS NULL OR dc.signed IS NULL)) src
 ON (tgt.id = src.id AND tgt.cn = src.cn) -- assuming these two columns are the primary key for the ft_t table
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.ss = 'X';
```